# Who is this green woman?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, star-trek-discovery

This appears to be a bounty hunter and is one of many who have captured Harry Mudd (or allegedly captured him). What is her name and race? She looks just like Gamora the Zen-whoberis. Is she Orion? She was possibly on the Qo'noS Embassy but I could not find her in *Will You Take My Hand*..

[image: Bounty Hunter]

Looks just like Gamora from Marvel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

She is an unnamed Orian guard (played by [Myrthin Stagg](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Myrthin_Stagg)), not a bounty hunter. She was in charge of the cell block where [Harcourt Fenton Mudd](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Harcourt_Fenton_Mudd) was being held in an Orion prison in one of the flashback scenes in [ST-ST S01E04: The Escape Artist](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Escape_Artist_(episode)).

[image]

Earlier, the same Short Trek vignette opened with an armored female bounty hunter selling Harcourt Fenton Mudd to a Tellarite bounty hunter, [Tevrin Krit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tevrin_Krit). This is likely where your confusion comes from. They are **not** the same human/alien being.

> A Tellarite bounty hunter, Tevrin Krit, purchases prisoner Harcourt Fenton Mudd from a female bounty hunter before she beams away and departs. Mudd pleads his innocence, only to have Krit bring up the United Federation of Planets' charges against him—and reward for his capture.
> <sub>source:[Memory Alpha - The Escape Artist](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Escape_Artist_(episode))</sub>

[image]

> The female bounty hunter was actually [Harcourt Fenton Mudd](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Harcourt_Fenton_Mudd) in disguise and he was selling an android duplicate of himself to the Tellarite. Perhaps he got the idea for the disguise from his former prison guard.

Comment: You might want to specify that Myrthin Stagg is the actress's name rather than the character's. According to Memory Alpha, the character's name [is not given](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Orions_(23rd_century)#Guard_.28female.29).

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've edited my response appropriately. The credits for that short only list her as *New Guard*.